# Java can't find the 'equal' method

Tags: java

I tried to check if a property was equal to a string but I keep getting this error

Code:

```
if (prop.getProperty("quit").equal("true")) {

}
```

Error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method equal(java.lang.String)
  location: class java.lang.String
```

Comment: the question title could use cleaning up, it's currently not very informational.  I'll have a go at answering this though

Answer (score 11):

The method name is [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) not `equal`.

Comment: Using an IDE, like Eclipse, can help avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: I was literally about to hit "post" when the orange bar of death appeared.  :(